# Using backpressure for keystroke in RxJs

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm trying to capture the user keystroke using RxJS, and for each stroke, generate a result object which contains the **key**, the **duration** of the stroke (time between `keyup` and `keydown` events), and the **interval** between previous strokes (using `timeInterval`).
See the image bellow for an overview.

So far, my code is working : `Hello` outputs `ShiftLeftHELLO`.

But when I writing **faster** (as usual I mean), everything breaks up and `World` outputs `ShiftLeftShiftLeftOLD`.

Do you have any suggestion on implementing [backpressure](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/backpressure.html), buffering or something else in my code to prevent this behavior ?

```js
(function (document) {
 var textarea = document.querySelector("#input");
  var keyUpStream = Rx.DOM.keyup(textarea);
  var keyDownStream = Rx.DOM.keydown(textarea);
  var keyStrokeStream = Rx.Observable.merge(keyDownStream, keyUpStream);

  var keystroke = keyStrokeStream.filter((function() {
    var keysPressed = {};
    return function(e) {
      var k = e.which;
      if (e.type == 'keyup') {
        delete keysPressed[k];
        return true;
      } else if (e.type == 'keydown') {
        if (keysPressed[k]) {
          return false;
        } else {
          keysPressed[k] = true;
          return true;
        }
      }
    };
  })())
  .distinctUntilChanged(function (e){
    return e.type + e.which;
  })
  .timeInterval()
  .bufferWithCount(2)
  .zip(function (evts){
    return {
      "ts" : Date.now(),
      "key":  evts[0].value.code,
      "evts" : evts,
      "duration" : evts.reduce(function(a, b){
        return b.value.timeStamp - a.value.timeStamp;
      })
    };
  }).subscribe(function (e){
    console.log(e);
    document.querySelector("#output").textContent += e.key.replace("Key", '');
    document.querySelector("#console").textContent += JSON.stringify(e);
  });
})(document);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs-dom/7.0.3/rx.dom.js"></script>
<h1>KeyStroke</h1>
<textarea id="input" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="console"></div>
```

[image: Streams]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: Rxjs noob here.

The problem is that your code expect a keyup from a key after a keydown from that same key. When you type fast, you have a race condition on keystrokes, resulting in a buffer with several keydowns or keyups. Not what you expect in your buffer.

I've modified the code to take advantage of your filter function. That function returns only keyup events and it saves the corresponding keydown stroke. This way, you calculate the interval within the filter function. I'm pretty sure that there's a more elegant solution using only RxJS functions but since you already used state in the filter function, I've modified it a little.

The snippet now shows a proper output. I think it solves your problem but it's not a good way of using RxJS (as I said we're storing state in the filter function).

```js
 (function (document) {
   var textarea = document.querySelector("#input");
   var keyUpStream = Rx.DOM.keyup(textarea);
   var keyDownStream = Rx.DOM.keydown(textarea);
   var keyStrokeStream = Rx.Observable.merge(keyDownStream, keyUpStream);

   
   var keystroke = keyStrokeStream.filter((function() {
     var keysPressed = {};

     return function(e) {
       var key = e.which;
       var result;

       if (e.type == 'keyup' && keysPressed.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         e.strokeInterval = Date.now() - keysPressed[key];
         delete keysPressed[key];
         return true;
       } else if (e.type == 'keydown') {
         if (!keysPressed.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           keysPressed[key] = Date.now();
         }
         return false;
       }
       return false;
     };
   })())
   .map(function (evt){
     return {
       "ts" : Date.now(),
       "key":  evt.code,
       "duration" : evt.strokeInterval
     };
   })
   .subscribe(function (e){
     console.log(e);
     document.querySelector("#output").textContent += e.key.replace("Key", '');
     document.querySelector("#console").textContent += JSON.stringify(e);
   });
 })(document);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs-dom/7.0.3/rx.dom.js"></script>
<h1>KeyStroke</h1>
<textarea id="input" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="console"></div>
```